# Oauth 2 Attribute provided with invalid value: Header:toType

Tags: google-apps-script, google-oauth, google-apps-script-addon

After deploying my Apps Script project script as a Google Sheets add-on, it gives this error when running OAuth2:

> Attribute provided with invalid value: Header:toType (line 303, file "Service", project "OAuth2")

My thing is, nothing has changed code wise apart from testing as an add-on. Why did this happen, and how can I resolve it?

Edit:

Here is the service function:

```
    function getBQService_() {

     return OAuth2.createService('BigQuery')
     .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth')
     .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
     .setClientId('CLIENT_ID')
     .setClientSecret('CLIENT_SECRET')
     .setCallbackFunction('authCallbackBQ')
     .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
     .setScope(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery',
             'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control',
             'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write',
             'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
             'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics'])
     .setParam('access_type', 'offline');

   }
```

Now this goes just fine, and of course fails to authenticate and rederects successfully, but the problem is after opening the link and logging into the google account is when I get that error.  Again this same code worked just fine up until it was tested as an add-on.

Comment: "why doesn't my oauth code work" -> perhaps you should **include said code in the question**.

Comment: Added, although I doubt the code is the problem, since it worked fine before it was tested as and add - on.